# How to add contents to script that needs to be append to head in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have a code:

```
let myScript = document.createElement('script');
myScript.setAttribute('src', url);
document.head.appendChild(myScript);
```

How can I add contents to script before appending, so that I'll have something like:

```
<script>
  // do something
</script>
```

Comment: Consider explaining your case. You preferably shouldn't. You can do this immediately in the place where you have this code by writing`// do something`. Or by using eval for dynamic script body, which is heavily discouraged for several reasons

Comment: I think you shouldn’t do that. If you would give more context, maybe there is a completely different solution. I did work for about 20 years in frontend projects and never ever had the need to do something like this.